# Separating components of a single object model in Core Data

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am designing the architecture for my data in Core Data. My question: I have a `List` object. Before I started using Core Data, I defined it as a subclass of NSObject, but now that I'm using Core Data, NSManagedObject, etc. I'm wondering if I should break up the components of my List object, like in this [introductory tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started) to Core Data.

Essentially, a `List` object is composed of a

```
NSString uniqueID
NSString name
BOOL completed
BOOL notifyMe
NSDate notifyDate
NSDate creationDate
```

This seems like a lot of data for a single object given that NSManagedObject forces you to load an entire object all at once. Does it make sense to make a one-to-one relationship between the `List` object, and say a new object called `ListDetails`, where `List` then becomes

```
NSString uniqueID
NSString name
BOOL completed
```

and `ListDetails` is

```
BOOL notifyMe
NSDate notifyDate
NSDate creationDate
```

Thanks in advance for your advice!

**Additional Caveat:**

Each `List` would also have a one-to-many relationship with an `Entity` called `ListItem`. So in other words, currently I have two `Entities`, a `List` and `ListItem`. If I break up `List` into two components (`List` and `ListDetails`), would my one-to-many relationship still be just with `List`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you feel fairly certain that the name or uniqueID are going to become super long, the memory footprint is going to be pretty small even with six attributes (especially when two are `BOOL`s).

If you find places where you need to grab a large number of the List entities but only need a couple of the attributes you can set up a fetch request that has it's return type set to dictionary and specify the attributes you want. For example you could grab all entities that aren't complete, need notification and the date has passed with a compound predicate and just have it return the name and uniqueID in a dictionary.

If you do break it up then `List` would likely be the center with relationships to `ListItem` and `ListDetails`.

If the notification date isn't something the user needs to see all the time you can also store it as an `NSTimeInterval` which is a little lighter than NSDate and easy enough to check if it has passed too.